# Tranfer function of non-self regulating process

Tags: fluid-mechanics, modeling, transfer-function, systems-engineering

[image]

This system is non-self regulating process with mathematical model :

dh/dt = (fi-fo)/C

where

fi = flow input,
fo = flow output,
C = tank capacity or volume tank.

I want make tranfer function of this system so from above mathematical model, I extend :

C = Q/A and
fo = a*sqrt(2gh)

therefore,

dh/dt = Q/A (fi-(a*sqrt(2gh))

is it right ? if it is right how to find tranfer function for output h and input qi?

Comment: what's Q and A? also the last expression, in the algebra looks like you substituted C for 1/C ?? Also this looks like homework.